# Translate "Those in Whom Deserts Hide" into Classical Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check

I am translating the phrase *Those in Whom Deserts Hide*, which was inspired by a line in the poem [Dionysian Dithyrambs](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche#Dionysian-Dithyrambs_(1888)) by Nietzsche ("The desert grows: woe to him in whom deserts hide").

This is my initial translation:

> Illi in Qui Solitudina Occultant

I'm fairly confident on my vocabulary choice, but not so confident on my conjugation and declension. *Solitudina* in particular concerns me, because while I think it's the right declension for plural accusative, I couldn't find any examples of it. Is this correct and does it make sense?

Comment: Have you tried using a participle rather than a relative clause?

Comment: Not yet. You're thinking something like _Occultas_, i.e. _Those in whom deserts are hiding_?

Comment: Like *occultans*. In general *illi qui occultant = occultantes*.

Comment: So _Illi Quibus in Solitudines Occultant (Occultans)_, or _Illi Qui Solitudina Occultant (Occultans)_? I was pondering about which to have in nominative after posting my question, since it _deserts_ is the subject and _those_ is the object.

Comment: @Adam, sorry I deleted my comment. it wasn't accurate. But  *Illi in Qui Solitudina Occultant* just seem off, because according to the rules or rel. clauses, the case of *qui* is determined by the role of it in the relative clause.

Comment: @Adam, continue: To render it like the English, I would go for: *Illi in quibus Solitudina se occultant* (here in the clause *Solitudina* is the subject, the obj. is *se* and the place of of hide is *ablative* *quibus*

Comment: Ahh, ok! Can you post this as answer? I like both your answer and the answer that @gmvh posted, but yours will have better visibility as a separate answer.

Comment: @Adam I was unclear, sorry. I wasn't commenting at all whether *occultare* is a good choice or how it should be used, just making the grammatical point that a participle can replace a relative clause and in cases like this it might be the most natural choice. This is not unlike English: "a horse that runs" = "a running horse". To compose a sentence, you'll also need to know whether you need an active or passive participle and whether you need some other words to go with it.

Comment: @d_e I agree with Adam: That'd make a fine answer!

Answer (score 6):

*Quibus latent deserta*.

*Latēre* = ‘to be hidden’;
*dēsertum* = ‘desert’ (quite common in Vulgate, but also in Vergil, see L&S s.v. *dēsero* *in fine*).

Comment: *Lateo* does seem the most natural choice of verb here. Note that as far as I can tell, it takes a bare ablative only in verse; in prose you would probably want *in quibus*.

Comment: Thanks! And, yeah, but the distinction prose/poetry is somewhat artificial IMHO (and arguably at least the original English phrase here is kinda poetry)!

Comment: @Batavulus: The [actual original](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Unter_T%C3%B6chtern_der_W%C3%BCste) is, of course, in German: "Die Wüste wächst: weh dem, der Wüsten birgt…"

Comment: Ah, please forgive my ignorance! In that case Crescit desertum / Crescunt deserta; vae illi (in) quo latent deserta.

Answer (score 5):

**desolationes (in se) abscondentes** — those that cover/hide deserts (within themselves)

Answer (score 5):

Keeping to vocabulary selection the same (I assume the word is *solitudo*), I think a straight-forward translation is:

> Illi in quibus solitudines se occultant

*solitudines* here is not the accusative case, but rather the nominative.

Another options is to use the passive voice instead of active *se occultare*. I like this option the better, as *desert* is not the active agent:

> Illi in quibus solitudines occultantur

I think in both cases the preposition *in* can be omitted without meaning change as *occulto* might take an ablative of means.

---

General note: [Though I used the indicative mood in the answer] I'm unsure if the subjunctive mood in the relative clause is necessary, but I think it might be better than the indicative here, since the clause is restrictive; especially where *Those* are simply general people and not specific.

Comment: I agree that indicative works only if the people are specific. But in the question's context they might actually be.

Comment: Would the passive work with _latentur_?

Comment: @Adam, I think passive would not work with *lateo*. since *lateo* already means somewhat passive "to be hidden"/to hide himself, where *occulto* is hide something. Not 100% sure though

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder if it would retain the feeling of being passive with just _latent_?

Comment: @Adam, I think so. example from Distichs of Cato: *Quod flumen placidum est, forsan **latet** altius unda* (For when the river is quiet, perhaps deeper water is hiding.)

Comment: @Adam, maybe better translation would be "...water is **hidden**"